# Can't insert data in sqlite database with Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am trying to save in a table some data, and, if it changes, update the value.

```
def saveobject(obj): 

    save=(obj.field1, obj.field2, obj.field3)

    con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

    with con:
        cur = con.cursor() 
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(field1 TEXT, field2 INT, field3 INT)")   
        allrows = cur.fetchall()
        print allrows
        if(len(allrows)==0):
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO Users VALUES(?,?,?)", save)
        else:
            for row in allrows: 
                if(obj.field1==row[0]):
                    if(obj.field2==row[1]):
                        print 'Object already Present'
                        break
                    else:
                        print 'Object field2 updated'
                        cur.execute("UPDATE Users set field2=(?) where field1=(?)", (obj.field2, obj.field1))
                       break
                else:
                    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Users VALUES(?,?,?)", save)   
                    print 'User added'

        print 'after ', cur.fetchall()
```

Running the program, verified that the object is correctly received by the method (I verified that printing "save" and everything is ok), I have the following output:

```
[]
after []
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(field1 TEXT, field2 INT, field3 INT)")   
allrows = cur.fetchall()

for row in allrows:
```

`allrows` is always zero length because the "create table" doesn't return a row.

Comment: `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Users")`  is this the solution?

Comment: Yes, but i think is better if you do:

`select * from Users where field1=value1 and field2=value2...`

Otherwise, you always will fetch all rows